# how to choosing distribution key in greenplum

Tags: key, psql, distribution, greenplum

I would like to know about how to choosing data type of distribution key that each data type different,can I using statement to distribution key ? such as WHERE, why greenplum using distribution key and if can I using index ? different?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [ask] a question.  You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

A good key is typically a unique identifier in a table and this can be a single or multiple columns. If you pick a good key, each segment will have roughly the same number of rows.

A customer table with a record per customer would be distributed by customer_id.

```
create table customer (
customer_id int not null,
customer_name text not null,
customer_address text)
distributed by (customer_id);
```

A data warehouse customer table where you have multiple sources loading your customer table may have an additional column describing the source. In this case, the customer_id may not be unique because two different sources may use the same customer_id to refer to different customers. So, you may have a customer table that looks like this:

```
create table customer (
source_id int not null,
customer_id int not null,
customer_name text not null,
customer_address text)
distributed by (source_id, customer_id);
```

The goal of table distribution is to spread the data evenly to all segments so that when you query the table, all segments can work in parallel to execute the query more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Column(s) which match many or all the thumb rules below make great data distribution candidates:

- Column(s) that are regularly used in JOIN’s (`SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B WHERE A.column1 = B.column1`)
- Column(s) that distribute table rows evenly across the segments. The more singular the values for a column, the more optimal their distribution. Here is what to check for:

  - Distinct values; the more the better (compared to table row count). Should have enough distinct values to allow distribution to all segments.
  - Maximum Row per Value; the fewer the better.
  - Maximum Rows `NULL`; the fewer the better. A very large number indicates a very large distribution spike. Large spikes can cause serious space consumption problems at the segment level.
  - Typical Rows per Value; the fewer the better. Monitor periodically as it might change over time.
- If a single column cannot achieve an even distribution, use a multi-column distribution key with a maximum of two columns. Additional column values do not typically yield a more even distribution and they require additional time in the hashing process.
- If a two-column distribution key cannot achieve an even distribution of data, use a random distribution.